# Custom dimension error - In about 10~15% of value is missed

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, gtag.js

Please understand that I am not good at English.

I set up the 'Custom dimension' to get user-ID.

```
var customerCode = ''; // This is going to be inserted when user log in.
gtag('config', 'UA-00000000-0', {
   'optimize_id': 'GTM-XXXXXXX',
   'user_id': customerCode,
   'custom_map': {'dimension1': 'userId'}
});
gtag('event', 'userId_dimension', {'userId': customerCode, 'non_interaction': true});
```

However, in about 10~15% of all sessions, user-ID are always missed.
But all other index of Custom dimension are being 100% collected.
I checked it in BigQuery.

So, to figure out the cause of the problem, I set up to push the Event value that is same with 'Custom dimension'.

```
gtag('event', 'event', {
   'event_category' : 'cdTest',
   'event_action' : customerCode,
   'event_label' : '',
   'non_interaction' : true
});
```

As a result, The Event was 100% collected, but user-ID for Custom dimension was still missed in about 10~15%.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. You could raise an issue here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I'll try this too.